# Limit of complex numbers

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

What would be the limit of following term?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{inx}}{2^n}$$

I tried to convert the $e^{inx}$ into trigonometric form and tried to do some simplification but got stuck after that.

Thanks. :)

Comment: $|e^{inx}| = 1$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: @sciona Could you please give more hints on how $e^{inx} = 1$?? Thanks

Comment: $e^{inx} = \cos nx + i\sin nx$, so $|e^{inx}| = |\cos nx + i\sin nx| = \sqrt{\cos^2 nx + \sin^2 nx} = 1$. The numerator is bounded and $2^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @rndflas, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106453/finding-the-limit-using-eulers-formula/1106460#1106460

Comment: @sciona Of course, only if $x$ is real.

Comment: @BartekChom ah! yes you are right. If $x = a+ib$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$), then $e^{ix} = e^{-bn}.e^{ina}$ and limit exists if $\frac{e^{-b}}{2} < 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Just as you tried $$\frac{e^{inx}}{2^n}=\frac{\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)}{2^n}$$ Each sine and cosine being between $-1$ and $1$, the numerator is finite and the denominator goes to $\infty$; thus, the limit is $0$.