# Finding the limit using Euler's Formula

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I need to find the limit of the following, by using Euler's Formula.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cos{x} + \frac{1}{2^2} \cos{2x}. . . . + \frac{1}{2^n} \cos {nx}\right)$$

Thanks

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is a duplicate. However, I can't find the original. Maybe I'm wrong . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{2^k}
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-\frac{e^{ix}}2}+\frac1{1-\frac{e^{-ix}}2}\right)\\
&=\frac12\frac{2-\cos(x)}{\frac54-\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac{4-2\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2^{k+1}}$, is a sum of two geometric progressions.

Summing the G.P.'s $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(e^{ix}/2)^{n+1} - 1}{(e^{ix}/2) - 1}+\frac{(e^{-ix}/2)^{n+1} - 1}{(e^{-ix}/2) - 1}\right)$

Comment: +1: the result can be simplified to $2 (2-\cos x)/(5-4\cos x)$.

Answer (score 2):

We need $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{\cos rx}{2^r}$

As $\dfrac{\cos rx}{2^r}$=Re$\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}2\right)^r$ and as $\left|\dfrac{e^{ix}}2\right|=\dfrac{|e^{ix}|}2=\dfrac12<1,$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}2\right)^r=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac{e^{ix}}2}$
$=\dfrac2{2-e^{ix}}=\dfrac2{2-(\cos x+i\sin x)}=\dfrac{2(2-\cos x+i\sin x)}{(2-\cos x)^2+(\sin x)^2}$

Comment: jst a quick question, i got everything except $\frac{e^{ix}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @rndflas, $|e^{ix}|=1$ right?

Comment: i thinks thats where i'm confused. Could you explain alittle bit more please.. thanks

Comment: @rndflas, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html

Comment: Okie.. one more question.. if i am not wrong, at the last time of your answer, isn't $1 - \frac{e^{ix}}{2} = 2 - e^{ix}$ and not $e^{ix} - 2$

Comment: @rndflas, Thanks for your observation