# Trigonometric Summation $\sum_{r=0}^∞ \frac {\sin(r θ)}{3^r}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

$$\sum_{r=0}^∞  \frac {\sin(r θ)}{3^r} $$

Given: $\sinθ=1/3$

I recently came across this question, and I tried numerous ways of solving it, but I could reach nowhere.
My initial approach was to expand uptil the first 3 terms to see if there was a pattern, but I don't think there is one. I also tried converting the question into a telescopic series, but I don't see how that can be done either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean calculating $\sum_{r=0}^\infty \sin(r\theta)/3^r$ if $\sin\theta=1/3$?

Comment: @RMWGNE96 yes, edited

Comment: MSE doesn't link properly, probably because of the aterisk (*). If you want to consult the link, then copy-paste into your browser

Comment: link is broken, takes me to the homepage of wolframalpha

Comment: Where does this problem come from? This falls under [adding context to your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: [Good Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+of+sin(n*csc%5E(-1)(3))%2F3%5En)

Comment: @RMWGNE96 when posting a link post it like this: `[example](link)`, like that it doesn't break

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106453/finding-the-limit-using-eulers-formula

Comment: Far relation : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769794/difficult-infinite-trigonometric-series

Comment: [WolframAlpha gives a solution, it's a big but algebraic expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+sin(n*arcsin(1%2F3))%2F3%5En+from+0+to+infinity)

Comment: Thanks @Holo for your general tip

Comment: @labbhattacharjee do you have a method which does not involve complex numbers? I haven't studied it yet, a solution involving something else would indeed be helpful

Comment: @MathDude3013, Serach for 'scale of relation' in  https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonplan00hobsgoog. Please let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum is $$\Im\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\frac13\exp i\theta\right)^r=\Im\frac{1}{1-\frac13\exp i\theta}=\Im\frac{1-\frac13\exp -i\theta}{\frac{10}{9}-\frac23\cos\theta}=\frac{3\sin\theta}{10-6\cos\theta}.$$For $\sin\theta=\frac13$, $\cos\theta=\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$, so the sum simplifies to $\frac{1}{10\mp 4\sqrt{2}}=\frac{5\pm 2\sqrt{2}}{34}$.

Comment: Still think that this is right, this is precisely what rolls out of WolframAlpha.

Comment: any alternate method, mate? I haven't yet studied complex numbers

Comment: @MathDude3013 Ooh, that's a tough one. If you *had* spotted a pattern, you could prove it by induction. Spoiler alert: the sum of the first $n$ terms is $$\frac{\frac{1}{3}\sin\theta-\frac{1}{3^{n}}\sin n\theta+\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}\sin\left(n-1\right)\theta}{\frac{10}{9}-\frac{2}{3}\cos\theta}.$$As $n\to\infty$, only the numerator's first term survives.

Comment: well, that is very hard to spot :(

Comment: @MathDude3013 Less so if you know $\sin A+\sin B=2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}$, but yes, very hard. This is probably why so many people learn complex numbers.

Comment: in about 4 months, I will be one of those people

Answer (score 1):

Use geometric series. We have
$$\begin{split}\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(r\theta)}{3^r}
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{ir\theta}}{3^r}\right)
\\&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{3}\right)^r\right)\\&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}/3}\right)\\&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1+e^{-i\theta}/3}{1+(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})/3-1/9}\right)
\\&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1+\cos(\theta)/3-i\sin(\theta)/3}{8/9+2\sin(\theta)/3}\right)\\&=\frac{-1/9}{8/9+2/9}\\&=-\frac{1}{10}\end{split}$$ if I didn't make a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: Should the 3 in the exponent of the second line be an $r$?

Comment: Yes, edited accordingly

Comment: You have some sign errors, which is why you got a sine, not a cosine, in your denominator. (The $1/9$ has a sign error too, but they're linked.)

Comment: Yes, you're right! You might want to edit my answer